# Read the name of an istream

Tags: c++, casting, file-extension, istream

I have something like that :

```
istream ifs("/path/to/my/file.ppm", ios::binary);
```

So now, for checking the extension file, It's necessary to get the name of the file.
I'm using my own function read :

```
 ... readPPM(std::istream& is) {}
```

It's is possible to get the /path/to/my/file.ppm in a string from the istream& variable ?

Comment: As an `istream` is a general-purpose input stream (and not necessarily associated with a file), the answer is no.

Comment: You could create a map of file name to pointer or reference_wrapper to `ifstream`.

Comment: something like map<string, ifstream> ? I only have one file, I don't think it's necessary to use a map

Comment: so use a std::pair - a map is only a container of pairs

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly actually used

```
std::ifstream ifs(...);
//    ^
```

However, even so the stream doesn't retain the name used to open it: there is rarely a need to doing so and it would be a wasted resource for most applications. That is, if you need the name later, you'll need to retain it. Also, not all streams have a name. For example, an `std::istringstream` doesn't have a name.

If you can't pass the stream's name separate from the stream, you *can* attach the name, e.g., using the `pword()` member:

```
int name_index() {
    static int rc = std::ios_base::xalloc(); // get an index to be used for the name
    return rc;
}

// ...
std::string   name("/path/to/my/file.ppm");
std::ifstream ifs(name, ios::binary);
ifs.pword(name_index()) = const_cast<char*>(name.c_str());

// ...
char const* stream_name = static_cast<char*>(ifs.pword(name_index()));
```

The stream won't maintain the pointer in any shape or form, i.e., with the above setup the `name` needs to outlive the `ifs` object. If necessary the objects stored with `pword()` can be maintained using the various callbacks but doing so is non-trivial.